# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 37312 while http post

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to post data to node API from flutter. my code is as follows.

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:3000";
Map<String, String> userBody = {
"firstName":"Vishal",
"lastName":"Soni",
"email":"vishal@gmail.com",
"mobile":"1234567890",
"password":"123",
};

Future<dynamic> postData() async {
try {
  http.Response res = await http.Client().post("$uri/register", body: jsonEncode(userBody), headers:    {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });
  print(res);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Getting following error
[image]

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to solve your problem -- I'd start with verifying your API is working properly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `localhost`. It should be your IP address.

```
     final String uri = "http://10.0.2.2:3000";
```

Look here for the same issue on [Github](https://github.com/hillelcoren/flutter-redux-starter/issues/16#issuecomment-408365042).

Comment: This is only applicable if you're running your app on an emulator, where 10.0.2.2 is looped back to the host machine's address

Comment: Yeah I'm running on an emulator

Answer (score 2):

run the below command in the terminal

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```